# Python3.8 `all()` not short circuiting

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

Okay I may just be having a bad workday but to my knowledge `all()` should short circuit [according to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

`all()` should be equivalent to:

```
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

Which is also equivalent to daisy chaining `and`.

So the following should do the same thing:

```py
all((True, print('This should print and stop'), print("this shouldn't print")))
True and print('This should print and stop') and print("this shouldn't print")
```

Yet the top one does both prints (i.e. fully evaluated each part)
but the bottom short circuited properly.

Is this a bug with Python (3.8.2) or am I not getting this right all of a sudden?

Repl with example: https://repl.it/join/scxbpnhc-syntactical01

Comment: In your `all` the second element is still *Trueish* since it is not empty.

Comment: `print()` returns `None` which is considered `Falsey` in a equivalency expression.

Comment: But `all` is doing what it is supposed to do: it returns `False` from the statement but needs to run `print` to establish the return. Running it causes the print...

Comment: It is no different than constructing the tuple `t=(True, print('this'), False, print('not this'))` That is done before `all` is ever called.

Comment: Yeah. Mentally, when I did it, I meant it to be a generator. The second I realized it was a tuple do to chepner's answer I saw my flaw and the relation to your comment. I still disagree with the "Trueish" comment since it was never Trueish, it was just evaluated do to be in the construction of a tuple.

Comment: I agree with the 'Truish' comment. I had a similar brain fart. It is the presence of the `()` call operator in the construction of the literal tuple -- before `all` is ever called -- that you are seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iteration inside `all` short-circuits, but each call to `print` has to evaluate in order to create the `tuple` you pass as an argument before `all` is ever called.

There's no simple way to create an arbitrary lazy sequence in Python without a `def` statement. You can write

```
def foo():
    yield True
    yield print("This should print and stop")
    yield print("this shouldn't print")

all(foo())
```

but there's no pure expression equivalent. You need to iterate over *something* to use a generator expression, for example

```
(x(y) for x, y in zip([id, print, print], 
                      [True, 
                       "This should print and stop",
                       "this shouldn't print"]))
```

would work as you expect.

```
>>> all(x(y) for x, y in zip([id, print, print], [True, "This should print and stop", "this shouldn't print"]))
This should print and stop
False
```

Now, `print` is called inside `all`, rather than as part of evaluating the argument to pass to `all`.

Comment: Interesting.... `print()` was just an example (my real code has functions) but I was unaware that I couldn't use `all` for lazy loading like this. Using `zip` to get around it is fascinating but I guess chaning `and`s is more readable. Thank you.

Comment: I would love if there was a way to write something like `(yield True, yield f(x), yield f(y))` as a generator expression, rather than requiring some sort of explicit iteration.

Comment: My first check looks to see if an `object is not None` then the second was actually working with the object (plus a few more) but I had the issue if it not short circuiting thus I was working with a `None` object. Ideally would be nice if all/any excepted `*args` but yield would be an interesting backwards compatible workaround.

Comment: Short-circuiting happens, just not where you want it. Arguments to `all` are evaluated, so if you want to defer a function call, it has to be wrapped in a generator.

Comment: *I would love if there was a way to write something like* Please see my answer. I think I gave you a good start on that...

Answer (score 1):

Python's `all` take an [iterable as an argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)

During the construction of the example in your question, in this case a tuple, the functions inside the tuple literal are called and the return value in inserted into the tuple literal; no differently than:

```
>>> tup=(True, print('this'), False, print('not this'))
this
not this
```

If you want to have a form of *assemble on the fly* you could do something like this:

```
def example_func(*args):
    return args

g2all=(True, (print, 'this', 'and this'), False, (print, 'not this'), (example_func,1,2,3,4))
```

This is relying on the fact that you can refer to a function by name and, without the `()` call operator the function is not called yet:

```
>>> g2all
(True, (<built-in function print>, 'this', 'and this'), False, (<built-in function print>, 'not this'), (<function example_func at 0x10d0a9430>, 1, 2, 3, 4))
```

You can then use that in an `all` with a generator:

```
>>> all(f[0](*tuple(f[1:])) if isinstance(f, tuple) and callable(f[0]) else f for f in g2all)
this and this
False
```

and the calling of the functions stop when `all` finds a Falsie value.

Comment: Possible at the cost of readability. Chaining `and` would be more readable. This checks for callables but it my real life usecase I am doing a getatrr for example: `all(*x is not None, x.valid is True, x.attributes.is_hashable is True))`. Your solution may help others though.